# how to sync develop branch with master

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-merge

I have master branch and develop branch. For pushing the changes from develop to the master i made a release branch and merged it with master using recursive strategy. But I forgot to merge the release branch with develop branch and deleted release branch. After that i made several commits to develop branch. Now develop branch is ahead and behind both from master. How to sync master and develop now ? I am using this [article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for learning git branching.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is the other way round:

merge master to dev
merge dev to master just after that
resolving all conflicts while merging.

Although git is superb when it comes to merging and handling branches, I don't think there is a quick way around resolving conflicts other than manual, tedious work using 3-way diff/merge tools.

Also, it helps to do what @cHao said in his answer below - merge often, merge small, and you will barely have large conflict merge situations.